# Perl regex grouping

Tags: regex, perl

I need help to split the following string into key/value pairs.

Example:

```
string='1256789: David - This is assigned to David 345678: Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike 456901: Roger - This is assigned to Roger'
```

I want to split the above string from matching pattern "[0-9]: Name -"

So I need key/value pairs as shown below:

```
1256789=>David - This is assigned to David
345678=>Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike
456901=>Roger - This is assigned to Roger
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You should show us what you've tried and what it produces, so we can help you correct your code, rather than expecting us to write the code for you.  We help people who've made a genuine attempt to solve a problem; we're less keen on helping people who've not shown what they've tried.  Have you come across negative lookahead yet?  (It won't be surprising if you haven't, but it could be material to solving your problem.  At least, one way to solve it uses negative lookahead.  There are probably others that don't.)

Comment: How did your data get into that mess in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

From your problem description, it's unclear whether your input string is delimited between records; in other words, are these just tied together with spaces or not? If so, the problem gets a little trickier. In this case, I'm just going to strip the string in chunks:

```
use strict;
# Concatenating these to suppress side-to-side scrolling:
my $string='1256789: David - This is assigned to David'
    . ' 345678: Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike'
    . ' 456901: Roger - This is assigned to Roger';
my %orders;
while( $string ) {
    my ($order, $desc, $rest) = $string =~ /^(\d+):\s+(.*?)\s*(\d+:.*)?$/;
    $orders{$order} = $desc;
    $string = $rest;
}
```

at which point, `%orders` will have what you want. It's a little awkward this way. With a different regex, using the `g` regex modifier, you could probably unload all of them in one expression, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way of doing the job.  It uses positive lookahead (not negative as I mentioned in a comment).

File: `pattern.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string='1256789: David - This is assigned to David 345678: Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike 456901: Roger - This is assigned to Roger';

while ($string =~ m/(\d+): (\w+ - .*?)(?=\s*\d+: \w+ -|$)/g)
{
    print "$1 == $2\n";
}
```

Example run:

```
$ perl pattern.pl | so
1256789 == David - This is assigned to David
345678 == Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike
456901 == Roger - This is assigned to Roger
$
```

The regex looks for a sequence of one or more digits, a colon, a sequence of word characters, and a dash, followed by a non-greedy string of any characters up to a trailing context.  The trailing context is either some spaces, some digits, a colon, a word, and a dash or the end of the string.  The match is applied repeatedly via the `g` modifier or suffix.

You can refine and improve the regex, using `\s+` in place of spaces, for example, and using `x` as a modifier to allow it to be split for easier comprehension:

```
while ($string =~ m/(\d+): \s+ (\w+ \s+ - \s+ .*?)(?=\s*\d+: \s+ \w+ \s+ - \s+ |$)/gx)
```

You could revise the printing to show that trailing spaces aren't included:

```
print "[$1] == [$2]\n";
```

which yields:

```
[1256789] == [David - This is assigned to David]
[345678] == [Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike]
[456901] == [Roger - This is assigned to Roger]
```

Etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of simple `split` operations is all that's required

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '1256789: David - This is assigned to David 345678: Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike 456901: Roger - This is assigned to Roger';

my @assignments = split /\s+(?=\d+:)/, $string;
my %assignments = map { split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2 } @assignments;

use Data::Dump;

dd \%assignments;
```

**output**

```
{
  345678  => "Mike - This order 000345 assigned to Mike",
  456901  => "Roger - This is assigned to Roger",
  1256789 => "David - This is assigned to David",
}
```

Comment: This works good,i issue i am facing is what should i do if there is colon after 000345: which is still valid and should go into 345678 => "Mike - This order 000345: assigned to Mike", the split should happens only between "1256789: David -" means a number: <word> <-> <space> rest should be ignored

Comment: That's impossible as you can't tell whether that's supposed to be `345678 => "Mike - This order"` and `000345 => "assigned to Mike"`

Comment: Can't we split based on <number>: <name> <-> <space> as a delimiter?

Comment: But the text is presumably manual input, so something like `000345: assigned - to Mike` is also possible? The best way would be to store the data properly in the first place. How did it get to be all on one line?

Comment: if there is '-' after 000345: it is possible to assign to Mike, but as long as there is no - it will   be consider part of the 345678, the data that comes in the format is <number>: <name> <-> <space> "string" is standard and rest of the things are can be anything 123456: xxxxxxxxxx etc,so the best possible combination should be <number>: <name> <-> <space> and rest we don't have control on it.

Comment: Exactly. You have no control over the text after the hyphen, so there's no way to tell if a new record has started or if someone has just typed in something that looks exactly like the start of a record. Whatever generated the data that you have should never have put it all on one line